# Как копировать текст в буфер обмена на python

Tags: python

У меня есть переменная `text` в которой храниться информация. Мне надо чтобы по вызову функции, эта информация копировалась в буфер обмена

Comment: В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала скачиваем библиотеку `pyperclip` (`pip install pyperclip`).

Эта библиотека сможет копировать в буфер обмена информацию.

Пишем код:

```
#Импортируем pyperclip
import pyperclip

#Делаем переменную text с информацией
text = 'ваша информация'

#Делаем функцию которая принимает переменную text
def write(name):
    pyperclip.copy(name) #Копирует в буфер обмена информацию
    pyperclip.paste()

#Вызываем функцию записи в буфер обмена
write(text)

#Наслаждаемся результатом
```